# How do I get the nodejs version inside a nodejs program?

Tags: node.js, version

In a [debugger for nodejs](https://github.com/rocky/trepanjs), there is a command to show the V8 version and the debugger package version. How can I get the nodejs version?

I imagine I can basically run a command `node --version` or `nodejs --version`, but I'm hoping there a is way to do with without running an external shell command – which is not only slower but, depending on paths, might give a different answer.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Use [`process.version`](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_version) to get the version of Node that is running:

```
console.log('Node version is: ' + process.version);
```

Comment: While I wait the requisite 8 or so minutes to accept this answer, I'll kill time by saying thanks and commit https://github.com/rocky/trepanjs/commit/81a68a6c8fb0507e041effadf8f06937728ff32e acks your help.

Comment: And I see I can use `process.versions` which also gives the v8 version. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11707698/how-to-know-which-javascript-version-in-my-nodejs/11707742#11707742